# housewife (but if she has a job?)

Tags: word-choice

What is the word in English for "a good housewife" if she has a paid job? In a dictionary "A housewife is a married woman who does not have a paid job, but instead looks after her home and children." But if she has a job?

The context is the following:

> Margaret is **a good housewife**. She is preserving tomatoes now.

EDIT:
*Esther* said correctly about my idea in the post: compliment about someone's "housewifely" skills.

Comment: Every term I can think of would sound like an insult because it would assume that certain jobs are reserved for women. In many homes where the wives work, the traditional jobs are shared. My case is a good example. I am the husband. When I am home, I do all the cooking. If tomatoes needed to be preserved, I would do it.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney, my question isn't about that you wrote.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, because if she has a job outside of the house, she is not a housewife.  Are you asking about a term for someone who does all those housewife-type things, but *also* has a job?

Comment: You might as well ask what a mechanic is called if he has a part-time job as a driver. He is both a mechanic *and* a driver.

Comment: I know what you're looking for, because I am aware of such a term in other language(s) (where you can compliment someone's "housewifely" skills without the implication that that's all they do). But I am not sure there is such a thing in English.

Comment: [balebusta](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/baleboste) (various spellings exist because the word comes from Yiddish) has the meaning you are looking for (ie, you can call someone "such a balebusta" for preserving tomatoes, even if they also work outside the home). However it isn't really a mainstream English word, and the direct translation is "housewife," which does not have the same implications.

Comment: There isn't really a word for it. In the days before modern appliances, canned and frozen food etc. etc., running a household _was_ a responsible. full-time job, but nowadays many people think of a 'housewife' as just 'a woman who lets her husband keep her' - the terminology hasn't kept pace with social changes.

Comment: @Esther, I suppose you understand me right. It's very strange if there is no this word in English.

Comment: *She can bring home the bacon and fry it up in a pan.  And never, never let you forget.....*  Well, I can't really remember the rest but it was a commercial that aired in the 70's.  The protagonist of the commercial was a woman who could do everything a man could do and also do 'womanly' things at the same time.  Bacon is a slang term for money, particularly wages.  She was stepping out and moving up.  That was the 70's.  We just call her a woman now.  Same as we did in the 60s.

Comment: The closest thing would be to compliment someone for their "domestic skills" but honestly this isn't something that really people would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to hear the tongue-in-cheek expression **domestic goddess**.  It's said of a woman who's a great cook, looks after the house  and is also a bit sexy too. Maybe among the "woke" generation it might be considered sexist or prejudicial against men, as  its male equivalent –*[domestic god](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22domestic%20god%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsbQlDAzU2WQIViaJybSI3UZU1bIxw%3A1660675000064&ei=uOP7YrGgA9aP9u8Poc-BkAs&ved=0ahUKEwix3Ny7gMz5AhXWh_0HHaFnALIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22domestic%20god%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMggIABAeEAcQCjIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEB4yBggAEB4QCjIICAAQHhAPEAoyBggAEB4QCDIGCAAQHhAIMgYIABAeEAg6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEB4QFkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDkClijJWCBK2gBcAF4AIABbIgBjgKSAQMyLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*–is rarely used.

> Margaret is what I call a **[domestic goddess](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/domestic-goddess)**. As we speak, she's bottling her homemade tomato sauce.

A domestic goddess, which is British English but easily understandable to American English speakers, needn't be married or be financially dependent on anyone. She might be living with a partner and they might share one or more children from their previous marriages. There is nothing that says a *domestic goddess* cannot look after the house *and* have a full-time job too.

Comment: Is it idiomatic to say "a good domestic goddess" or simply "domestic goddess"?

Comment: @Sergei The "good" is implicit in "domestic goddess", she wouldn't be called a *goddess* if she was a terrible cook. Also, *good* (without context) could suggest someone who is well-behaved, obedient or a kind person. I'd leave "good" out, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

One possibly acceptable alternative could be: *Margaret is a good **homemaker**. She is preserving tomatoes now.*

But I don't think this quite works, as I'll explain below.

You're not going to find a close translation of the phrase "Margaret is a good housewife" that sounds acceptable to contemporary English speakers.  This is due largely to the societal changes ushered in by second-wave (1960s-'80s) feminism, and additionally to changes in household maintenance that aren't directly related to women's liberation.

In other words, this isn't just a language translation problem, it's a culture translation problem.

In the modern, English-speaking world, not very many people (of any gender) preserve tomatoes.  If you told me that a person were canning tomatoes, I would think that they were into cooking, maybe into gardening, possibly into food blogs, maybe into Instagram (and the pseudo-hippie/back-to-nature-via-technology aesthetic that pervades that platform).

I would probably *not* make any assumptions about this person's interest or proficiency in cleaning, household finance, schedule-making, party-planning, or whatever else might be involved in *housewifery* (or what I've called *homemaking*).

This seems to be the crux of the matter: among English-speakers, there is no consistent conception of what it takes to be a good homemaker.  Do you have to cook, or is it enough to order takeout?  Do you need to clean, or can you just be in charge of finding a cleaner?  Does a homemaker mow the lawn, or is that part of the masculine-coded housekeeping activities that would now be called...?

If you're describing a person in a different culture, you can definitely translate this idea into English, but not with shorthand terminology like *housewifery*/*homemaking*/*doing work around the house*.  You'd need to say something like, "In SomeCountry it's expected that women do X, Y and Z.  Margaret is very good at these things.  She's preserving tomatoes now."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should consider whether you want to use the term 'housewife'. Some people are fine with it, as it traditionally describes a wife that looks after the home rather than working remuneratively. Some men are happy with 'househusband' which denotes a reversal of the old-fashioned dynamic. However, some find these terms demeaning and instead prefer other terms such as 'homemaker', or 'full-time mother' (or parent) if they have children and stay home for this reason.

There is no special term for someone that does two jobs. For example, a person that worked part-time as a mechanic and part-time as a driver is both a mechanic *and* a driver. So, a person might say they are both a housewife *and* the occupation they have.

I do hear people add 'part-time' and 'full-time' to domestic/family roles to indicate that they either split their time or devote all their time to something. For example "*a full-time mother*" might describe a mother who cares for their children all week and does not have a remunerative job. Someone else might describe themselves as "*a part-time [job title] and housewife/mother*" as a way of indicating why they chose part-time work over full-time employment.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a word that can be used to compliment someone's "housewifely" skills, not a word to describe a part-time housewife.

Comment: @Esther Such a word doesn't exist. He's saying "good housewife", which suggests that to be any good at it, she would have to devote a certain amount of time to it. That's pretty insulting, no wonder there isn't a word. My suggestions, which are used, just show how time is apportioned between roles. It doesn't suggest someone is good at it or not.

Comment: not really, there is exactly the word the OP is looking for in Yiddish (with no negative implications), and possibly in OP's native language such a word exists as well, but I agree that no equivalent word exists in English.

Comment: @Astralbee, Esther said correctly about my idea in the post: **compliment about someone's "housewifely" skills**.

Comment: Banish housewifely skills. We say homemaking skills.